# How to reset the button action in tkinter after every click?

Tags: python, tkinter

While I learning about the buttons in tkinter. I had a problem with it. I need my button to always reset the old action and want to do the new action.

```
def clicked():
    res = "THANKYOU " + txt.get()
    res1 = Label(mainwin, text=res, font=("Arial Bold", 35))
    res1.place(relx=0.5,rely=0.5,anchor='center')
```

In the above program whenever I execute the `clicked()` function, it must reset the old thank you message and it want show the thank you message with the new values in `txt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the thank you message `res1` outside `clicked()` and update its text using `res1.config(text=...)` inside `clicked()` instead:

```
def clicked():
    res = "THANKYOU " + txt.get()
    res1.config(text=res)

...
res1 = Label(mainwin, font=("Arial Bold", 35))
res1.place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5, anchor='center')
...
```